# Wht is the noun from the verb RECEIVE?

Tags: nouns

What is the noun of "Receive"? I need to frame this sentence :

> This is the date of your (Receival/Receiving/receipt).

What is the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

The correct word could be *receipt* or *reception*.

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/receipt?s=t) lists both definitions as:

> the act of receiving or the state of being received.

Comment: In practice there is a distinction, isn't there?  Receipt can be of gifts, money, deliveries.  Reception can be of guests, an audience, a lecture.  There is some overlap, but not a lot.